# How to partition data by some starting and ending values in SQL?

Tags: sql

For example, I have table:

| id | to_part |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | -1 |
| 123 | -1 |
| 123 | -1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | -1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | -1 |
| 123 | -1 |
| 123 | -1 |
| 123 | -1 |

What I want to do is partition data by to_part column that start in "interval" with value 1 and ends with -1. To better understand look in desired output table.

Desired output:

| id | to_part | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 | 1 |
| 123 | -1 | 1 |
| 123 | -1 | 1 |
| 123 | -1 | 1 |
| 123 | 1 | 2 |
| 123 | -1 | 2 |
| 123 | 1 | 3 |
| 123 | 1 | 3 |
| 123 | 1 | 3 |
| 123 | 1 | 3 |
| 123 | -1 | 3 |
| 123 | -1 | 3 |
| 123 | -1 | 3 |
| 123 | -1 | 3 |

Comment: An SQL table is unordered set of rows. Your table lacks an ordering column so the mission is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `LAG()` analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN to_part = 1 AND
                          LAG(to_part, 1, -1) OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                                    ORDER BY order_id) = -1
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS counter
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT id, to_part,
       SUM(counter) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_id) AS "rank"
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

Note carefully that my answer assumes that there exist a column called `order_id`, which maintains the sequence order you perceive in your sample data.  Sans this column, your question in general cannot be answered.

Comment: It doesnt work, it just assignes some fixed rank. In my case is 3.

Comment: Apologies...I posted wrongly.  Try the updated answer, after you have added `order_id`, which maintains the ordering of the rows.  You absolutely need such a column because SQL tables are modelled after unordered sets.